# Video autoplay function toggle

Tags: javascript, video, vimeo, playlist, autoplay

Could someone tell me what is wrong with my code ?

I want a function that has a toggle(checked /unchecked) to play a video playlist.

I mean the function that "youtube or Lynda.com" have , those two websites play a playlist with toggle, if a user don't like the videos play continuously they can turn the toggle off to autoplay a chapter.

I wrote some code which is supposed to play the next video when the initial one is ended, but it is not working.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>test</head>
    <body>
    <p>test script<p>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.4.0/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>

    <p><input type="Checkbox" id="autoplay"  onclick="check()" value="1" />Autoplay</p>

    <div id="vimeo">
    <iframe id="player" width="590" height="360" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/218543813?api=1&player_id=player" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <script src="http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('#autoplay').click(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
    var player = $f(document.getElementById('player'));
    player.addEvent('ready', function() {
    player.api('play');
    });

    var iframe = $('#vimeo iframe')[0],
    player = $f(iframe);

    // When the player is ready, add listeners for pause, finish, and playProgress
    player.addEvent('ready', function() {
    player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
    });

    function onFinish(id) {
      window.location.href = 'https://vimeo.com/channels/staffpicks/218543813';
    }
    })

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```